# Error : Can't find variable: forcetkClient

Tags: angularjs, salesforce, ionic-framework, hybrid

I am trying to build a hybrid application for salesforce. I am building the application for iPad. Currently i am trying to read the "Account" Object data for both online and offline mode by using a smartsync concept provided by salesforce. I am getting the issue as **"Error: Can't find variable: forcetkClient"**. Can anyone help me to identify the problem. This issue arises as soon as i call the fetch function    of the account model.

Comment: Found the solution. The issue was in old force.mobilesdk file. I just updated it to the latest version.